# How to make SVG element a link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

How to make each element of svg image embeded in HTML file (such as circle etc. with some class) an active link? 
I need to have one svg image that represents some elements and they should be clickable links.

That's the fragment of SVG image:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="612px" height="792px" viewBox="0 0 612 792" enable-background="new 0 0 612 792" xml:space="preserve">
<a href="http://google.com" ><rect x="-124.203" y="112.232" fill="#E88324" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="175.362" height="226.087"/> </a>
```

I made a second div:

```
<div class="displayer" style=" width:100%; height: 100%;">
</div>
```

And tried to do this using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $("a").click(function() {
        // $("body").hide();
        $(".displayer").load("http://google.com");
});
    });
```

But it doesn't make sense, how would you do that?

Comment: You don't need to declare all the namespaces for an svg inside HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it, test in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9d0y1ncb/)

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 width="612px" height="792px" viewBox="0 0 612 792" 
 enable-background="new 0 0 612 792" xml:space="preserve">
    <a xlink:href="http://google.com">
      <rect x="-124.203" y="112.232" fill="#E88324" 
        stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" 
        width="175.362" height="226.087"/> </a> 
</svg>
```

You just forget about `xlink:href` in `<a>` inside `svg`